# Elastic Search returns inconsistent results on running the same query multiple times

Tags: search, elasticsearch

We have indexed Data using elasticsearch on a single node. And we have a thread running in the background used for updating the index with the recent changes.

Now we are using elastic search API's to run the search query.

```
{
  "from" : 0,
  "size" : 20,
  "timeout" : 0,
  "query" : {
    "filtered" : {
      "query" : {
        "query_string" : {
          "query" : "Bug-157099*",
          "default_field" : "_content",
          "default_operator" : "and",
          "allow_leading_wildcard" : true,
          "analyze_wildcard" : true
        }
      },
      "filter" : {
        "fquery" : {
          "query" : {
            "query_string" : {
              "query" : "pxObjClass:(\"ProjMgmt-Work-Project\")",
              "default_field" : "_content",
              "default_operator" : "and",
              "allow_leading_wildcard" : true
            }
          },
          "_cache" : false
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "fields" : "*"
}
```

However , the search query returns inconsistent results. on rerunning the query continuously, sometime we get 0 results, sometime partial results and at sometimes we get complete results.

We are facing this issue in a cluster where only one node is an indexing node.

Can you let us know what might be causing this issue?

Comment: Can you give us more information: e.g. what query do you use?

Comment: Its a filtered query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue was due to the timeout set in the query. In some part of our code  we are setting the timeout to zero. We corrected the code and now the query is working fine.

I have inserted the correct query here

```html
{
  "from" : 0,
  "size" : 20,
  "query" : {
    "filtered" : {
      "query" : {
        "query_string" : {
          "query" : "BUg-157099*",
          "default_field" : "_content",
          "default_operator" : "and",
          "allow_leading_wildcard" : true,
          "analyze_wildcard" : true
        }
      },
      "filter" : {
        "fquery" : {
          "query" : {
            "query_string" : {
              "query" : "pxObjClass:(\"ProjMgmt-Work-Project\")",
              "default_field" : "_content",
              "default_operator" : "and",
              "allow_leading_wildcard" : true
            }
          },
          "_cache" : false
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "fields" : "*"
}
```